# Magento calling a catalog/product_list type block from product page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, product

I'm using a simple custom block to list products from a given category in the side bar. It works fine when called as

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" before="-" name="product.leftnav" as="product.leftnav" template="catalog/product/training_leftlist.phtml" />
```

On all pages *except* the product pages, where it causes an error (I get the item page with the 404 page below it).

Is there a better block `type` I should be using, or a different way of calling it on the product page?

Template file is:

```
<?php
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('status',1)
->addStoreFilter()
->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(12));

$products->setPageSize(4)->setCurPage(1);

$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

Then print the items with something like

```
if(count($products>0)) echo "<ul>";
foreach($products as $_product):?>
  <li>
    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
  </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php if(count($products>0)) echo "</ul>";?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to use a different `block type` for each place.

For the non-product pages

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" before="-" name="product.leftnav" as="product.leftnav" template="catalog/product/training_leftlist.phtml" />
```

Then for the Product pages use `type="catalog/product_list_related"`. Remembering to remove the above too, *e.g*:

```
<catalog_product_view>

    <remove name="product.leftnav" />   

    <!--  Left bar product list-->
    <reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/product_list_related" before="-" name="product.leftnav.view" as="product.leftnav.view" template="catalog/product/training_leftlist.phtml" />
    </reference>

</catalog_product_view>
```